# set options for all checkboxes, based on values in range

Tags: excel, checkbox

This question originated as a request for help to set the caption for all checkboxes to a cell range. After some trial and error, i've been able to get that happening, but for some reason, I can only set the caption for them.

I'd like to also set their visibility if the cell they're getting their caption from is blank. I'd also like to link them to another cell range (offset fromt eh caption cell by (0,1).

Maybe it's best to set the visibility if the caption is blank, rather than if a cell value is blank. not sure, but here's what I have so far:

Here's the code to set the captions:

```
Sub SetCaptions()

Dim Top As Long, Bottom As Long, i As Long, x As Long
Dim AvailableOptions As Range
Dim CompatibleOptions As Range

Top = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Styles", Range("B1")).Row
Bottom = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Options", Range("B" & Top)).Row
Set AvailableOptions = Range("B" & Top + 1, "B" & Bottom - 1)
i = AvailableOptions.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Set CompatibleOptions = Range("P" & Top + 1, "P" & Bottom - 1)
x = CompatibleOptions.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Range("B21").Value = "Avail Options: " & i
Range("P22").Value = "Compat Options: " & x

Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim chkbox As msforms.CheckBox
Dim a As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim c As Range

With ActiveSheet
    b = 0
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf obj.Object Is msforms.CheckBox Then
        b = b + 1
    End If
    Next
    Range("P20").Value = "Checkboxes: " & b
End With




For n = 1 To b
    For Each c In AvailableOptions
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            With ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & n)
                .Object.Caption = Cells(Top + n, 16)
                .LinkedCell = Cells(Top + n, 17)
            End With
        End If
    Next c
Next n
End Sub
```

In case it helps, here's the code used to generate the boxes:

```
Sub MakeCheckboxes4()
'delete all checkboxes
'create new checkboxes for all values in B
'set captions from P
'hide checkboxes where P is blank

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet

Dim obj As OLEObject
For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf obj.Object Is msforms.CheckBox Then
        obj.Delete
    End If
Next

Dim xSize As Integer:    xSize = 2      ' horizontal size (number of cells)
Dim ySize As Integer:    ySize = 1      ' vertical size

Dim t As Range
Set t = sht.Range("R23").Resize(ySize, xSize)

Dim Top As Long, Bottom As Long, i As Long
Dim AvailableOptions As Range, CompatibleOptions As Range
Top = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Styles", Range("B1")).Row
Bottom = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Options", Range("B" & Top)).Row

Set AvailableOptions = Range("B" & Top + 1, "B" & Bottom - 1)
i = AvailableOptions.Count

Dim c As Range

For Each c In AvailableOptions
    If c.Value <> "" Then
    sht.Shapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", Left:=t.Left, Top:=t.Top, Width:=t.Width - 2, Height:=t.Height
    Set t = t.Offset(ySize)
    End If
Next c
SetCaptions

End Sub
```

And then for linking cells:

```
Sub LinkCells()
Dim Top As Long, Bottom As Long

Top = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Styles", Range("B1")).Row
Bottom = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Options", Range("B" & Top)).Row

Dim i As Integer
Dim chk As Variant

i = Top + 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each chk In .OLEObjects
        If TypeName(chk.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
            chk.LinkedCell = .Range("Q" & i).Address
             i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End With
End Sub
```

And for Hiding the checkboxes

```
Sub HideCheckboxes()

Dim Top As Long, Bottom As Long, i As Long, x As Long
Dim AvailableOptions As Range
Dim CompatibleOptions As Range

Top = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Styles", Range("B1")).Row
Bottom = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Options", Range("B" & Top)).Row
Set AvailableOptions = Range("B" & Top + 1, "B" & Bottom - 1)
i = AvailableOptions.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
Set CompatibleOptions = Range("P" & Top + 1, "P" & Bottom - 1)
x = CompatibleOptions.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count



Dim obj As OLEObject
Dim chkbox As msforms.CheckBox
Dim a As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim c As Range

With ActiveSheet
    b = 0
    For Each obj In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf obj.Object Is msforms.CheckBox Then
        b = b + 1
    End If
    Next
End With




For n = 1 To b
    If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CheckBox" & n).Object.Caption <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("checkbox" & n).Visible = True
    Else
        ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("checkbox" & n).Visible = False
    End If
Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is creating the checkboxes? that is probably the place to be doing this

Comment: I updated it with the code as requested. Thanks for the reply. I don't necessarily have to generate the boxes every time I call the sub.

Comment: I've updated this again after finding a way to set the captions to the cell range. Now, I need to set other parameters, such as: visibility, linked cell, etc. Not able to get that to work. towards the bottom of `Sub SetCaptions()`, there is a line that I was trying to use for this purpose, but it doesn't seem to do anything. `.LinkedCell = Cells(Top + n, 17)`

Comment: Updated yet again to share the code I landed on that will clear all checkboxes, create new ones, set the captions from a range of cell values, link to certain cells, and then hide the ones with a blank caption. Super fun!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the magical code for linking checkboxes that finally worked for me

```
Sub LinkCells()
Dim Top As Long, Bottom As Long

Top = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Styles", Range("B1")).Row
Bottom = Range("B:B").Find("Feature Options", Range("B" & Top)).Row

Dim i As Integer
Dim chk As Variant

i = Top + 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each chk In .OLEObjects
    If TypeName(chk.Object) = "CheckBox" Then
        chk.LinkedCell = .Range("Q" & i).Address
         i = i + 1
    End If
Next

End With
End Sub
```